# Creating a function to scan user input

Tags: javascript, search

I am new to java script, I have some experience but am still learning. My question is: "how do I create a function that check the users input(text) for specific words. then displaying an image I set for those particular words?" As stated i am new so detailed explanation is helpful. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with event listeners and the `indexOf` or `match` methods (among other possibilities). Here's an example using jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="theInput"/>
<div id="images"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#theInput')
    .on('change keyup', function() {
        clearImages('#images');

        if ($(this).val().match(/smile/i)) {
            addImage('#images', 'https://s.yimg.com/lq/i/mesg/emoticons7/1.gif');
        }

        if ($(this).val().match(/cool/i)) {
            addImage('#images', 'https://s.yimg.com/lq/i/mesg/emoticons7/16.gif');
        }
    });

function addImage(selector, url) {
    $(selector).append('<img src="' + url + '"/>');
}

function clearImages(selector) {
    $(selector).html('');
}
```

This will add an image if the user enters text containing "smile" or "cool".  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/6rb3Ly9x/)

**Edit:** And here's a plain-JavaScript version:

```
function addImage(selector, url) {
    document
        .getElementById(selector)
        .innerHTML += '<img src="' + url + '"/>';
}
function clearImages(selector) {
    document
        .getElementById(selector)
        .innerHTML = '';
}
function doImages() {
    clearImages('images');

    if (this.value.match(/smile/i)) {
        addImage('images', 'https://s.yimg.com/lq/i/mesg/emoticons7/1.gif');
    }

    if (this.value.match(/cool/i)) {
        addImage('images', 'https://s.yimg.com/lq/i/mesg/emoticons7/16.gif');
    }
}

var theInput = document.getElementById("theInput");

theInput.onchange = doImages;
theInput.onkeyup = doImages;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/sLp7gs9x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [Event Listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) in Javascript. You can use them to detect when there is input in a text field.